# ELK - Logstash exclude host

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

this is my first experience with the ELK stack and I'm trying to filter some hosts through the Logstash (v7.11) drop function but obviously I'm doing something wrong because despite trying to exclude the host using the variables: ip, hostname, type seems to ignore them anyway

Currently the json looks like this:

```
{
  "_index": "syslog-2021.02",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "w83syncB6OFB5F4c_Fkq",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "host": {
      "id": "2d716776-19df-4dfe-8022-497a1539bb58",
      "name": "DOM1.contoso.com",
      "hostname": "DOM1",
      "architecture": "x86_64",
      "ip": [
        "fe80::247b:aa07:b20:a19",
        "192.168.1.100"
      ],
      "mac": [
        "00:18:3a:4f:5d:4b"
  ],
  "os": {
    "kernel": "10.0.17763.1577 (WinBuild.160101.0800)",
    "name": "Windows Server 2019 Standard",
    "version": "10.0",
    "platform": "windows",
    "build": "17763.1577",
    "family": "windows"
  }
},
"log": {
  "level": "information"
},
"tags": [
  "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
],
"agent": {
  "version": "7.11.1",
  "id": "0cf7eacf-d605-46d4-a9cb-b0f7b5991c97",
  "hostname": "DOM1",
  "ephemeral_id": "f702e826-9c20-4140-8a0b-5ba6a5c46050",
  "name": "DOM1",
  "type": "winlogbeat"
},
"ecs": {
  "version": "1.7.0"
},
"winlog": {
  "record_id": 144825686,
  "keywords": [
    "Audit Success"
  ],
  "channel": "Security",
  "api": "wineventlog",
  "provider_name": "Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing",
  "provider_guid": "{54849625-5478-4994-a5ba-3e3b0328c30d}",
  "opcode": "Info",
  "event_id": 4634,
  "computer_name": "DOM1.contoso.com",
  "task": "Logoff",
  "process": {
    "thread": {
      "id": 2664
    },
    "pid": 956
  },
  "event_data": {
    "LogonType": "3",
    "TargetUserName": "testuser",
    "TargetDomainName": "CONTOSO",
    "TargetLogonId": "0x5016a75e",
    "TargetUserSid": "S-1-5-21-1960408961-362288127-682003330-2659"
  }
},
"event": {
  "code": 4634,
  "action": "Logoff",
  "provider": "Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing",
  "created": "2021-02-22T18:07:41.305Z",
  "kind": "event",
  "outcome": "success"
},
    "message": "An account was logged off.\n\nSubject:\n\tSecurity ID:\t\tS-1-5-21-196040961-865488157-6821234550-3259\n\tAccount Name:\t\ttestuser\n\tAccount Domain:\t\tCONTOSO\n\tLogon ID:\t\t0x5016A75E\n\nLogon Type:\t\t\t3\n\nThis event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer.",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2021-02-22T18:07:39.812Z"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-02-22T18:07:39.812Z"
    ],
    "event.created": [
      "2021-02-22T18:07:41.305Z"
    ]
  },

  "sort": [
    1614017259812
  ]
}
```

The config file looks like:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 514
    type => syslog
  }
  udp {
    port => 514
    type => syslog
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "winlogbeat" {
  drop { }
}

  if [hostname] == "DOM1" {
  drop { }
}

  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
 elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "syslog-%{+YYYY.MM}"
       }
stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no field named `type` or `hostname` in your document, that's why your conditional is not working.

You have a field named `agent.hostname` with the value `DOM1`, there is also a field named `host.hostname` with the same value and there is a field named `agent.type` with the value `winlogbeat`, you need to use one of those fields in your conditional.

The following conditional should work.

```
if [agent][hostname] == "DOM1" {
    drop {}
}
```

Comment: What other index? The config you shared has only one index. Are you running logstash using a directory with other config files? If this is what you are doing, you can't use the `drop` filter, if you drop a document it won't reache the `output` stage. If you want to exclude some kinds of documents from some index, you need to use conditionals in the output stage.

Comment: it was a typo in the other config file, works like a charm